NextAuth: Unable to re-direct to the New User Page
I'm not able to figure out why the redirect to NewUser page is not happening when user Signs In with the CredentialsProvider. The authorize function definitely returns the "isNewUser" flag as true for new users.
See config below:
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import axios from "axios";

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: "magic-link",
      name: "Magic Link",
      credentials: {
        token: {
          label: "Token",
          type: "text",
          placeholder: "Paste your magic link token here",
        },
      },
      authorize: async (credentials) => {
        try {
          // Validate the token with the backend
          const response = await axios.get(
            `http://localhost:3001/auth/magic-link?token=${credentials.token}`
          );
          const { user, backendTokens, isNewUser } = response.data;


          return { ...user, backendTokens, isNewUser };
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error validating magic link:", error);
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: "google",
      name: "Google",
      credentials: {
        query: { label: "Query", type: "text" },
      },
      authorize: async (credentials) => {
        try {
          // Forward the entire query string to the backend
          const response = await axios.get(
            `http://localhost:3001/auth/google/callback?${credentials.query}`
          );
          const { user, backendTokens, isNewUser, expiresIn } = response.data;
          console.log("Magic link response", {
            user,
            backendTokens,
            isNewUser,
            expiresIn,
          });

          return { ...user, backendTokens, isNewUser };
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error during Google authentication:", error);
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      console.log("JWT callback", { token, user });
      // Check if this is the first time the JWT callback is called (user is defined)
      if (user) {
        token.user = user;
        if (user.backendTokens) {
          token.accessToken = user.backendTokens.accessToken;
          token.refreshToken = user.backendTokens.refreshToken;
        }
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      console.log("Session callback", { session, token });
      session.user = token.user;
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      session.refreshToken = token.refreshToken;
      return session;
    },
    async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
      console.log("Redirect callback", { url, baseUrl });
      // Check if the URL is a callback URL
      if (url.startsWith(baseUrl)) {
        return baseUrl;
      }
      return url;
    },
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/signin",
    newUser: "/auth/new-user",
  },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

The re-direct never goes to /auth/new-user. It always just goes to "/". How can I fix this?
This is my /auth/magic-link endpoint where the magic link directs to. I have credentialsProvider as I'm using a NestJS backend for sending emails and generating tokens, authenticating, etc.

We do not need to use redirect callback.
Have you specified a callback url?
signIn("credentials", {
  //...
  callbackUrl: `/auth/new-user`
})

or you can redirect users conditionally
import type { SignInResponse } from "next-auth/lib/client"
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react"

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"

const Page = () => {
  const router = useRouter()

  const onSignInHandler = () => {
    signIn("credentials", {
      //..
      redirect: false,
    })
    .then((res: SignInResponse | undefined) => {
      if (!res.ok)
        alert("Something went wrong!")
      else (res.ok)
        router.push("/auth/new-user")
    })
  }

  return (
    <>
    </>
  )
}

Read more on https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#specifying-a-callbackurl
